# Planes and surfaces and normal vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Is a plane the same thing as a surface? and is the normal vector the same at every point on both??

Comment: Usually, if people talk about surfaces (in the smooth sence), they have nonlinear, i.e. bent, surfaces in mind. E.g. the boundary of a ball in Euclidean 3 space, but not every surface will look that regular. And in that case the normal vector may vary from point to point.

Comment: Is the difference therefore a plane has the same normal vector at every point whilst a surface does not?

Comment: A (smooth embedded) surface will have a tangent plane at each point, and a normal to that plane is a normal to that surface in that point. In case you have a $2$-dimensional surface in $3$- dimensional space the space from which you may take a normal vector is one dimensional, and if you fix the lenght there are up to sign to choices in each point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A plane is a surface with zero curvature i.e. does not bend
2. The normal to the plane is the same at every point.
3. The normal to the surface is not necessary a fixed vector
4. Example of the plane is the xy-plane
5. Example of the surface is the sphere

Answer (score 0):

1.Tangent vector on plane lies on plane but may not lie on surface.  2. Every plane is surface but not conversly